# Laravel 5 send push notification to android and ios device

Tags: android, ios, laravel, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging

I took the [package](https://github.com/davibennun/laravel-push-notification)

I set up on the instructions. I decided to test to do so

```
$token = DeviceToken::find($id);
    $deviceToken = $token->device_token;
    PushNotification::app('appNameAndroid')
        ->to($deviceToken)
        ->send('Hello World, i`m a push message');
```

but it gives an error 401 Forbidden; Authentication Error

in what could be the problem? help
a problem in the device token? What length should be the  device token?

Comment: Hello Rai i am trying to implement push notification with laravel .but i can't figure it out. can you please help me out in this ?

Comment: @Nomi sorry I was not here for a long time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not an issue with the device token but rather an issue with your server's API key. Refer to the 401 error definition and recommended action [here](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/http-server-ref?hl=en#error-codes).

This usually happens when you have an API key but have not enabled the "Google Cloud Messaging for Android" API in the Developers Console.